# Enable VPC-native (alias IP) on an existing GKE cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a way to enable `Alias IP` on existing GKE cluster (with disabled `Alias IP`)?

(Besides using https://github.com/bowei/k8s-custom-iptables to create NATs on each node)

Comment: Feature to enable IP aliasing on existing cluster(IP alias disabled) is currently not available. It appears currently creating and managing manual [routes](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/routes) and configuring NAT gateway is the option to get functioning of the GKE IP aliasing on existing GKE cluster with IP aliasing disabled.  Feel free to submit a feature request using Google cloud [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49722435/kubernetes-on-gke-external-connection-through-nat-for-specific-kube-services) may help

Answer (score 3):

As per GCP  VPC-native cluster's documentation, A cluster that uses Alias IPs is called a VPC-native cluster, and [you cannot migrate a routes-based cluster to a VPC-native cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips#restrictions).  There is already a feature request for this. You would have to recreate the cluster or as you have mentioned, configure manual routes with NATs to get it working.